# Change Grid Background Color Inside Listview when Selected

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, grid, background-color

I have a grid inside a listview. I want that when the listview item is selected, the grid background is blue and for those that are unselected it is white.

XAML:

```
<ListView
    x:Name="kategoriListView"
    Margin="35,20,30,20"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsListView"
    AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    CornerRadius="15,15,15,15">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <UserControl>
                <Grid
                    x:Name="grid"   
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                    Height="50"
                    Background="White"
                    CornerRadius="15,15,15,15">
<TextBlock
                                                        x:Name="kelasText"
                                                        Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                        FontSize="17"
                                                        FontWeight="Bold"
                                                        Foreground="Black"
                                                        Text="{Binding KategoriList}" />
                </Grid>
            </UserControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundSelected" Color="Blue" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundUnselected" Color "White" />
    </ListView.Resources>
</Listview>
```

I tried it like the XAML above, but it didn't work and the Grid background is still white when the listview item is selected

Comment: I used your code and got the behavior you were expecting, the selected background is blue. How did you add the list Items?

Comment: I have edited the code above

Answer (score 0):

The `ListViewItemBackgroundSelected` works for the container (the ListViewItem) but not the **UserControl** that you put in the DataTemplate.  If you want to change the background color of the `Grid`inside the template, you will need to find the `Grid` using [VisualTreeHelper Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper?view=winrt-22621).

So here are the steps:

1. Handle the **SelectionChanged** event of the `kategoriListView`
2. Find the selected `Grid` control using **VisualTreeHelper**
3. Change the background color of the selected `Grid` to blue.
4. Find the unselected `Grid` control
5. Change the background color of the selected `Grid` back to white

Here is the code that you could check.

**Xaml:**

```
 <ListView
        x:Name="kategoriListView"
Margin="35,20,30,20"
VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        SelectionChanged="kategoriListView_SelectionChanged"
AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsListView"
AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
... more code
```

**Code behind:**

```
    public DependencyObject FindChild(DependencyObject parant, string name)
    {
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parant);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var MyChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parant, i);
            if (MyChild is FrameworkElement && ((FrameworkElement)MyChild).Name == name)
                return MyChild;

            var FindResult = FindChild(MyChild, name);
            if (FindResult != null)
                return FindResult;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void kategoriListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {  
        // get selected listviewitem
        ListViewItem item = kategoriListView.ContainerFromItem(kategoriListView.SelectedItem) as ListViewItem;
        // the DependencyObject is the grid that you want to get
        DependencyObject targetelement = FindChild(item, "grid");

        Grid selectedText = targetelement as Grid;
        selectedText.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

        if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            // change unselected item color 
            ListViewItem removedItem = kategoriListView.ContainerFromItem(e.RemovedItems.FirstOrDefault()) as ListViewItem;
            DependencyObject removedelement = FindChild(removedItem, "grid");

            Grid removedText = removedelement as Grid;
            removedText.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }

    }
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I've tried the code above, but got an error like this image: https://imgur.com/a/lb5ffA0

Comment: @cielo Please share the code snippet about how do you use my solution.